# assigning instance names to multiple mcs

Tags: flash, instance

I am wondering if anyone knows of any extensions or scripts that assign instance names to multiple mcs at once. I have the same mc on hundreds of keyframes and I have to convert them to graphic symbols to animate then back to mcs for scipting but they lose their instance names. I've read a post on this forum that came close to helping me with some JavaScript but when I tried it I got syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had some people help me out with this script:

```
var name = prompt("Name?");
//var name = "face";
for(i in fl.getDocumentDOM().selection)
{
    fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[i].name = name;
}
```

Works perfectly!